# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://nameservice1/kylin_metadata/kylin-..., excepted: hdfs://node111a11:8020

Tags: hadoop, cube, kylin

when I  start use kylin to Scheduling cube，I meet the following error:
The job log of Cube as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://nameservice1/kylin_metadata/kylin-..., excepted:
hdfs://node111a11:8020
at org. apache hadoop. fs File System. checkPath(Filesystem. java: 662)
at org. apache hadoop hdfs. DistributedFileSystem getPathName(DistributedFileSystem java: 22
at org. apache hadoop hdfs. DistributedFile System accesss0oo(DistributedFileSystem java: 113)
at org. apache hadoop hdfs. DistributedFileSystem$ 20. doCall(DistributedFileSystem. java: 1265)
at org. apache hadoop hdfs. DistributedFile System$ 20. doCall(DistributedFileSystem java: 1261)
at org. apache hadoop. fs. FileSystemLinkResolver resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver java: 81
at org. apache hadoop hdfs. DistributedFile System getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem java: 1261)
at org. apache hadoop. fs FileSystem exists(FileSystem. java: 1418)
at org. apache kylin. common util. HadoopUtil getFilteronly Path(HadoopUtil java: 146)
at org. apache kylin engine. mr steps. CreateDictionary Job$2. getDictionary (CreateDictionary Job java: 78)
at org. apache kylin cube cli. DictionaryGeneratorCLI processSegment (DictionaryGeneratorCLI java: 62)
at org. apache kylin cube cli. DictionaryGeneratorCLI processSegment(Dictionary GeneratorCLI, java: 49)
at org. apache kylin engine. mr steps. CreateDictionary Job run(CreateDictionaryJob java: 66)
at org. apache hadoop util. ToolRunner run(ToolRunner java: 70)
at org. apache hadoop util. ToolRunner run(ToolRunner java: 84)
at org. apache kylin engine. mr. common Hadoop shell Executable dowork(Hadoop ShellExecutable java: 62)
at org. apache kylin job execution. DefaultchainedExecutable dowork(DefaultchainedExecutable java: 64)
at org. apache job execution. AbstractExecutable execute(AbstractExecutable java: 125)
at org. apache kylin job. impl. threadpool. DefaultschedulerSJobRunner run(Defaultscheduler, java: 144)
at java util. concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor java: 1149
at java util. concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor $worker. run(ThreadPoolExecutor java: 624
at java. lang Thread run(Thread. java: 748)
result code: 2
```

Comment: have you configured the correct HDFS file system ?

Comment: yes ,I am, the problem has solved, thank you!

Comment: @wangwenhui how did you solve the problem? i a running into similar